# How to use string in method to create a dynamic parameter for Web Service in Android Application Java

Tags: java, android, api

We are building our first android application using web service. In one of the activity we call a web service to get assigned city to each user.

So far we tried to hard code any user on this method for "admin"

`private void getCitiesService()
        {
        APICalls obj= new APICalls(CitiesActivity.this,APIParameters.ACTION_CITIES  + "&user=" + "admin", null, CitiesActivity.this);
            String params =  "Get";
            obj.execute(params);
            referenceText.setText(params);
        }`

and it is getting the right data.

Now we want to replace "admin" above with a string of username getting from Login activity here

```
`SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("cApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
            pref.edit().putString("webUserName", edUser).commit();
            Intent n = new Intent(this, CitiesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);`
```

Then we called it on our CityActivity here and to test we print as textview and it is working fine.

```
 `SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("cApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    userName = prefs.getString("webUserName", "UNKNOWN");
    userNameDefault.setText(userName);`
```

Now we would like to use "userName" as a string inside above mentioned method something like this:

```
        `APICalls obj= new APICalls(CitiesActivity.this,APIParameters.ACTION_CITIES  + "&user=" + "userName", null, CitiesActivity.this);`
```

We have tried as a string and variable both means "userName" and userName but it didn't work.

However it isn't working. So obviously we are doing something wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add the user name as a parameter to the getCitiesService method.

```
private void getCitiesService(final String userName)
{
    APICalls obj = new APICalls(
        CitiesActivity.this,
        APIParameters.ACTION_CITIES  + "&user=" + userName,
        null,
        CitiesActivity.this);
    String params =  "Get";
    obj.execute(params);
    referenceText.setText(params);
}
```

Comment: hi mate, sorry didn't see your reply until now. We did tried that but still didn't work :( my code is now look like this

    `private void getCitiesService(final String userName)
  {
   APICalls obj= new APICalls(CitiesActivity.this,APIParameters.ACTION_CITIES  + "&user="+ userName,
     null, CitiesActivity.this);
   String params =  "Get";
   obj.execute(params);
  }`

As you mentioned.